# SSRS report with AS/400 data source keep running while in design preview is OK

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, odbc, ibm-midrange

I developed a `SSRS` report on `SQL server 2008 R2 BI`, the report retrieves purchase order data from our ERP server which is on `AS/400 platform`.

I used `ODBC` to connect AS/400 database. 
When I was designing, the report could be displayed in `'preview'` mode with correct result.

But after I published the report to `SSRS server` and tried to run it there, the report kept running, no result would come out.

I tried both shared data source and embed data source, the results were same.

I also clicked `'Test connection'` in data source, there was no response, too.

I'm guess the problem is on SSRS connection to AS/400, but cannot figure out why the `'preview'` works.

Comment: What error messages are displayed and/or found in logs? Is there a firewall between the SSRS server and the IBM i? Does the SSRS server have the right credentials to connect to the IBM i?

Comment: @BennyHill Thank you Benny. No firewall between SSRS and IBM I. The credentials should be OK because it works in design preview. I just ran the report on SSRS server again, the report still could not show result. I didn't find any error in the logs, here I attached them, please take a look.

Comment: @BennyHill Hi Benny, I could not paste the logs in prior comment because of the size limit. I check the log again, found below errors:<br/>library!ReportServer_0-5!1708!02/19/2014-14:17:25:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: , An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.;

Comment: And this one - *session!ReportServer_0-5!1708!02/19/2014-14:17:25:: e ERROR: Error in GetSnapshotData: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.*

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error messages, I'd guess that while in preview mode, SSIS is doing a

```
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS
```

But when trying to full back the full results set SSIS is timing out..

As a quick fix, you could increase the timeout on SSIS.  But the right way to fix things would be to either improve the performance of the query with additional indexes and/or modify the query to retrieve less rows.

Do you have any idea how many rows you're trying to pull back?

Have you tried running the query from the Run SQL Scripts component of IBM i Navigator?

From within Run SQL Scripts, you also have access to Visual Explain which will show you the query plan and recommend missing indexes.

Comment: Thank you @Charles. My SSRS report has 3 datasets, data source is the same. Here is one of my datasets query: `SELECT     a.companyno, a.ponumber, a.line#, a.product, a.sdescription, a.quantity, a.price, a.orderdate, b.product, b.vendorproduct, b.vendorproductdescription, c.eccn, c.draw2
FROM         podetail as a left outer join productvendor as b on  a.product=b.product left outer join productmaster as c on a.product=c.product
WHERE     a.companynumber = ? AND a.ponumber = ? AND a.poReleasenumber = ?
ORDER BY a.line#` <br/> It's quite simple, should return a couple of records, not much more.

Comment: Did you run the query's from Run SQl Scripts?  Also, the OS tracks every query issued, take a look at the plan cache under the Databases node of  System i Navigator.  Or you might consider starting a detailed performance trace; also done via Databases node of Navigator.